# UISplitView Landscape Mode

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller

I have downloaded an example code from [here](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/sample_code/Psychologist%20with%20Dr%20Pill_0.zip) and tested it out. The thing I wasn't able to understand is that when I set the orientation to Landspace only and run it in Portrait mode, nothing changes.. I mean I should still be able to see the menu on left and the Psychologist button shouldn't be there.

PS: With iOS6, it is working well but lower versions giving me the same result.

Comment: have you tried `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
}`

Comment: yes but the result is the same.. whenever I rotate it, it goes back to the single view mode..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in the RoatatableViewController.m file the method

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:
```

Is telling the app that rotation is okay in all directions.

You should use this to block to landscape mode for iOS 5 and older:

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation);
}
```

It just looks like the person who made this project up in Stanford overlooked this.